# Loop cut not loop

Tags: modeling

Why my loop cut is not a loop?
I am trying to make a loop cut with the loop cut tool but it doesn't make it though the entire object.
[image]

Comment: Loop cuts only work with quads that follow an edge ring

Answer (score 4):

Your topology does not allow for that. It appears that you go from quadrangles on the left to a triangle on the right, where there is no where for an edge to continue.

Essentially this:

[image]

versus

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer so the way to fix this to apply is triads to quads?